# or in regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

I am using this `(?<=^.*?;).*` expression to parse out user id one by one. It works good because they are separated by `;` but fails when it gets to the last person who does not have `;` at end of his/her id. To get to the next id I use `^.*?;`

All is fine but the when it goes `aharris` it fails and keeps giving me `aharris`. This `^.*?;` should not give me `aharris` because `(?<=^.*?;).*` already gave me `aharris`.

Sample string:

```
jsmith; bbrown; kosborne; aharris
```

Now, is there a way to add or switch `^.*?;` where it will give me empty string if the last person does not have `;`

I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1):

The way the example string is structured, you can use the following pattern to break it down:

```
"((?:^|; )(?<userId>.*?))+"
```

The first subset of parenthesis is a "non-capturing" group that matches either the beginning of a line (for the first item), OR a semicolon followed by a space (for all others). The second subset of parenthesis will match any set of characters nongreedily (meaning the smallest set of characters will be used that result in a match for the entire pattern), and "capture" them in a collection that can be referenced by its name, "userId".

Use this pattern in the following way (requires referencing/using System.Text.RegularExpressions and System.Linq):

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var userIds = match.Groups["userId"].Captures.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

When finished, userIds will be an instantiated `List<string>` populated with all four of the userIds from this string.

Comment: Keith: thanks for the posting but I am using Nintex Workflow which sits on SharePoint workflow engine and takes .net regex. I can't instantiate var in the nintex.

Comment: Well this is a .NET regex, so the pattern still works as long as whatever actual mechanism you use fully supports the .NET regex dialect and allows retrieval of captured groups.

Comment: Can it be if-then-else? for example, if no ; found in the provide string then give me nothing. if found then use ^.*?;

Comment: I tried this but not working. if(^.*?;)then(^.*?;)(?:else(null))?endif

Comment: @KeithS, the `$` in your regex should be `^`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 "jsmith; bbrown; kosborne; aharris".Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList()
```

instead.

The discussion in the comments leads to the following proposal:

```
 Regex.Matches("\w+(?=\s*;)", "jsmith; bbrown; kosborne; aharris").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. if(^.*?;)then(^.*?;)(?:else(null))?endif

Comment: usr: I tried your method but it returns mwaktin if i input mwatkin. It should return nothing. however, if i have mwakin; then i expect to mwatkin

Comment: Do you need the last name to be dropped if the string does not end with a semicolon??

Comment: for some reason nintex workflow is not translating your regex and still returning. That's okay. I think I am going to add another conditional action item to look for ; in the string that I am passing in regex. Thanks for all your help.